# keep getting python value error password_generator

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtaBZ.png)I have been watching the techwithtim videos and having trouble with password_generator. I keep getting a ValueError: to many values to unpack(expected 2).  I have the exact same code as the tutorial. is there something wrong with the password.txt file?  code. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLS35.png)

Comment: [*Please do not post text as images*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, cannot be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments, and cannot be copied and pasted to test and debug. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring in this line:

```py
user, passw = data.split("|")
```

The split function will split a string into a list and the splits will occur wherever the given token (in your case `|`) is found in the string e.g.

```py
data = "MBBison | StackOverFlow | Question"
result = data.split("|")
print(result) # Will be ['MBBison ', ' StackOverFlow ', ' Question']
```

If you instead did the following:

```py
data = "MBBison | StackOverFlow | Question"
a, b, c = data.split("|")

print(a) # Will be MBBison 
print(b) # Will be StackOverFlow 
print(c) # Will be Question
```

This is esentially equivalent to the following:

```py
data = "MBBison | StackOverFlow | Question"
result = data.split("|")
a, b, c = result

print(a) # Will be MBBison 
print(b) # Will be StackOverFlow 
print(c) # Will be Question
```

What happens here is that you take each value from the list generated by the split function and assign it to your variables `a`, `b`, `c`. For this to work correctly though, you need to be sure that the list will have exactly three values. Otherwise, you will encounter the error: `too many values to unpack` if the list had more values than the number of variables you used or `not enough values to unpack` if the list has fewer values the number of variables you used.

In your case, the error occurred because when you split the `data` variable, the list returned by the split function had more than 2 values and when you tried to assign those values to the `user` and `passw` variables, you did not have enough variables to go around. You can see what values that list has by doing:

```py
print(data.split("|"))
```

To make this work, you need to ensure that your `data` string is correct.